# code in VBA excel

Tags: vba, code

I need help with macro. The goal is to find specific text inside each sheet. If this text is found, macro continues with next codes. If the text is not found, macro skips to the next sheet and do the same. I have following code below. Could you help me, please?

```
  For Each wrkb In Workbooks
    If Not (wrkb Is ThisWorkbook) Then
    wrkb.Activate


        For Each wrksheet In wrkb.Worksheets

                Dim rng As Range
                 Range("A1:K1000").Select
                Set rng = Selection.Find(What:="AAABBB")
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                 wrksheet.Activate
                ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then
                Next wrksheet
                End If
```

"Next wrksheet" doesn't work without "for".

...when the condition "if" is fulfilled, next code (not specified here) is processed...

Comment: Use `for each workbook: for each worksheet:`

Comment: I sent incomplete code. Below is the right one:

Comment: Yes, code is edited

Comment: What is the final goal? To activate first worksheet with specified text fragment? to select the cell with this fragment? the same, but last? something else?

Comment: when the condition fulfilled, the code continues (inserts data to some cells etc. - this next code is well proven and works). When not fulfilled, code jumps to next sheet (no modifications in the current sheet). I only need to modifiy the conditons (selection of the RIGHT sheets), what is we are discussing about.

Comment: Your description is confusing. Please edit your question and clarify: what the code does now? What it should do instead?

Comment: Although the remaining code is huge a working, I do not want to specify it here. I need to find certain text inside each sheet: 1) if the text exists there (this is RIGHT SHEET), fill specified cells with values, formulas, links etc. 
(for example 
Range("X3").Select 
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10000"      ...etc.
Those codes after "end if" from assignment are correct and working !!!

2) if the text doesn't exist in the sheet - don't do any modifications here (this is WRONG SHEET), jump to next sheet a start from 1)

Answer (score 0):

Draft code:

```
For Each wbk In Workbooks
    For Each sht In wbk.Sheets
        If wbk Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit For
        With sht.UsedRange
            Set OneCell = .Find(What:="AAABBB")
            Do
                If OneCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Call PerformNeededAction(OneCell)
                OneCell = .FindNext(OneCell)
            Loop
        End With
    Next sht
Next wbk
```

Comment: Call PerformNeededAction(OneCell)    Compile error: Sub of Function not defined

Comment: Of course. It is your subroutine which "inserts data to some cells etc. - this next code is well proven and works". You must have its code. The "base" cell is transferred into it as a parameter. You may add more parameters if needed (for example, the reference to worksheet/workbook, or the value of some property - sheet name, workbook path, etc.). Or you may insert your code immediately into my code instead of Call (but I do not recommend).